# Run-Time Error 438 (Inherited Macro at Work)

Tags: excel, vba

So I "inherited" the job of handling macros that we run in my department at work, and I've mostly been doing a good job of maintaining them and sorting through the mess I received considering I'm garbage with VBA, but as of today I'm coming across a problem which is giving me trouble since it's not in a section of code I've ever altered.

I have a master version of the file we use, and save it as a template for everyone else to use (so they can't mess with my stuff), however when I came in today and tried to open the file, I immediately got a RTE 438 on the very first of my "Set" lines. As I mentioned, nothing about this code has changed from Friday (when it was working fine). Any suggestions on what I can edit to get rid of this issue?

Screens are as follows:

Start Screen:
[image: Start Screen]

Error:
[image: Error]

And the code associated when I run the debug is:

```
Public Function InitializeLists()
     Dim wsData As Worksheet
     Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

     Dim yearList As MSForms.ListBox
     Dim cboProv As MSForms.ComboBox
     Dim cboDoB As MSForms.ComboBox
     Dim cboSpaces As MSForms.ComboBox
     Dim cbo6097 As MSForms.ComboBox
     Dim cboSelectType As MSForms.ComboBox
     Dim cboMinimize As MSForms.ComboBox

     Set yearList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListBox1     'Error appears on this line
     Set cboProv = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ComboBox2
     Set cboDoB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ComboBox2
     Set cboSpaces = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ComboBox3
     Set cbo6097 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ComboBox4
     Set cboSelectType = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ComboBox5
     Set cboMinimize = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ComboBox6
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Is there a control named `ListBox1` on the "Data" worksheet?

Comment: After looking through my code a bit more, and discovering that this problem was only happening to a couple of select people, we discovered that it wasn't a problem with the macro, but an error that was generated by an update to some users' OS.

Appreciate the help.

And yes, there was a control set for ListBox1.